# Change backgroundcolor of text in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the backgroundcolor of the text in a textarea.

NOT the background color of the textarea. The background of each character.
Like selecting the text.

I want to see the spaces at the end of each line. Or a single line without text and only spaces. The color should appear even on typing new text.

If possible I don't want to use javascript. Only CSS.

It should look like this:
[image]. This one is selected text. I want it to see it without selecting.

Comment: It is impossible to set the background color just for the text in the `textarea` tag. The screenshot you've provided is most likely an overlay like a `div` with an attribute `contenteditable`, which takes value from the actual `textarea`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript for highlighting text in textarea.

```js
const bgcolor = "#3297FD";

const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
const bgtext = document.getElementById("highlight");

function highlight() {
 bgtext.innerHTML = "";
 let val = textarea.value;
 let len = val.length;
 for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (val[i] == "\n") {
   bgtext.innerHTML += "<br />";
  } else {
   bgtext.innerHTML += "<span style=\"background-color: [[bgcolor]];\">&#32;</span>".replace("[[bgcolor]]", bgcolor);
  }
 }
}

setInterval(highlight, 0);
```

```css
.text {
 position: fixed;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: transparent;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: monospace;
 white-space: pre;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<style>
.text {
 position: fixed;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: transparent;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: monospace;
 white-space: pre;
 color: white;
}
</style>
<p id="highlight" class="text"></p>
<textarea id="textarea" class="text" style="left:17px; top:18px;"></textarea>
```